# No editor descriptor for Manifest on opening old Android project with latest Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, workspace, eclipse-adt

i installed the latest version of Eclipse (Neon) using the eclipse installer in which i choose **Eclipse for Android Developers**.
I opened a workspace in which there is one project created with an old version of Eclipse (**Android Development Tools**) of a couple of years ago.
When i open Eclipse it prompts the following error:

**No editor descriptor for id com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.manifest.ManifestEditor**

I get this instead of the content of the Manifest file.

Here is the log output:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2016-08-17 11:24:38.314
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Executable extension definition for "class" not found.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.throwException(ConfigurationElement.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2829)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2016-08-17 11:24:38.324
!MESSAGE Executable extension definition for "class" not found.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2016-08-17 11:24:38.325
!MESSAGE Executable extension definition for "class" not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-08-17 11:24:38.406
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for the org.eclipse.ui.IStartup extension contributed by the 'org.eclipse.sequoyah.device.framework.wizard' plug-in.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Executable extension definition for "class" not found.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.throwException(ConfigurationElement.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2829)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2016-08-17 11:24:38.406
!MESSAGE Executable extension definition for "class" not found.
```

There is no LogCat output due this error:

**Could not create the view: com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.views.LogCatView**

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Why cant you migrate to Android Studio ?

Comment: Because i have no time to learn how to migrate and how to use it. I have just to update an old Android application.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html and https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html  might help. Moving forward this might help you

Comment: At the moment i have to make a 1 minute edit to the app and publish it, i can't migrate.

Comment: I solved installing Eclipse 3.8. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The change to the Android tools being at Eclipse.org changed the plug-in and editor IDs. The old IDs would no longer work, so any Android tool editors you had open in that workspace would cause an error when reopening. They should still be there under their new IDs. Try **Resetting** the Perspective, or just go on as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just closing the erroneous view/editor and opening it again? Reopening should reference the new ID and work better.

if it's not enough, you'll have to clear your outdated file/editor association for Android file in the dedicated preference page.